# Odoo 10 - Qweb test if record is in a record set

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have `a=sale.order.line(5,)` and `b=sale.order.line(4,3,5,6,)`

How can I test in QWeb if `a` is in `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```xml
<t t-if="a in b">
    <!-- do something -->
</t>
```